# Android Full Screen on Tablet

Tags: android

I've developed an app on Android. The screen displays well on the mobile phone - eg shows full screen. But when I run it on my Samsung tablet 10 inch - it covers only a quarter of the screen. Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:padding="10px">
    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center" >
        <ImageView
android:id="@+id/mainheader"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="30px"
android:layout_y="5px"
android:src="@drawable/mainheader"
/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/err"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                        android:textColor="#FF0000"
 android:layout_x="80px"
android:layout_y="25px" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/usernamelbl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35px"
                        android:text="User Name"
                         android:layout_x="40px"
    android:layout_y="75px"/> 
        <EditText android:id="@+id/username" 
                        android:layout_width="150px" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_below="@id/err"  
                        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                                             android:layout_x="120px"
    android:layout_y="70px"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/passwordlbl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Password" 
                        android:layout_x="40px"
    android:layout_y="110px"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/password" 
                        android:layout_width="150px" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                        android:layout_x="120px"
    android:layout_y="105px"
                        android:password="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="login_click"
                                                android:layout_x="50px"
    android:layout_y="150px"
                        />
        <Button android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
                        android:text="Sign Up"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="signUp_click"
                                                         android:layout_x="130px"
    android:layout_y="150px"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My manifeast xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mpest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
              <activity android:name=".AddFarmActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".AddPestStepOneActivity"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".AddPestStepTwoActivity"></activity>
              <activity android:name=".ThankYouActivity"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".ReportListActivity" ></activity>
                <activity android:name=".ReportDetailsActivity" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity"   ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddPestActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddEnvironmentActivity"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".AlertActivity"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChangeUserImageActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
                <activity android:name=".ReplyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
                <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiverActivity"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: change the android sdk selected in the project properties. It must be less than 2.. Make it to 2.1 or . You could also try making the height of the outermost linear layout as fill parent which is currently wrap content

Comment: Its in the android manifest file, Manifest tab and specify min sdk version there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add these lines in your manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first two layout tags are both set to `wrap_content`. This means they only fill the screen as much as they need to show all the content.

Change them both to `fill_parent` as so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" // fill_parent here
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:padding="10px">

    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" //and fill_parent here

                    android:gravity="center" >
```

Answer (score 1):

try

LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
**android:layout_height="fill_parent"**
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="10px"

Answer (score 1):

try to change your layout_width value with **"fill_parent"** instead of **wrap_content**

perhaps this is helped out your problem :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I created a tool to scale your layouts proportionally on a tablet. The reason your layout doesn't look right even though you used dp units, is because you might have only designed for one "density bucket". There's four of these buckets: small, normal, large and xlarge(tablets).

You can find my tool and a guide here:

http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html